# Can not get appium to launch iPhone simulator

Tags: python, selenium, appium

I have written a simple python script:

```
from appium import web driver
import unittest

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '7.1'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone Simulator'
desired_caps['browserName'] = 'safari'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

But it got the following error log, as soon I executed my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iOSTest.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 35, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 121, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u"A new session could not be created. (Original error: ENOENT, stat '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Applications')"
```

My appium version is: 1.2.2
Configurations are:
Server address: 127.0.0.1  Port: 4723

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you perhaps have a simulator process already running?

Comment: To Bryan Oakley: Thanks but this is not the case. There is no simulator running.

Comment: The error message says `Original error: ENOENT`. This is the error you get if the OS can't find an file. One common reason this happens is if you made a mistake in where you tell an application to find its files. The path that failed is in the error message.

Comment: To Louis: thank you. I will take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find the simulator. What version of Xcode are you using?

Can you go to the below directory? Is there a 7.1 simulator in there?

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

1. Xcode 6 doesn't come with the 7.1 simulator by default
2. Appium doesn't have support for Xcode 6 currently. You need to use Xcode 5 for now.

Comment: I was not aware of Appium does not support for Xcode 6, thank you. I will give it another try.

Comment: Thank you very much sheeptest. I took a look into this folder. The problem is that I was somehow using 7.0 simulator instead of 7.1. Problem solved.